# how to send javascript array to controller in yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I have a view having multiple checkboxes.

When I select some textbox, I need to do some operation on them, so they should be passed to the controller.

How can I do this?

---

#### My JS function :

```
function myfun() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "http://localhost/newtemplate/index.php/product/dispatchdata/",
        dataType : 'json',
        data : { 
            idList : $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").serializeArray()
        },
        success :  function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function (data){
            alert('Error');
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is this URL `dispatcher.php` is right ? what is the error that you got ?

Comment: the url is right.. it gives an alert of error.. i don't know whether it going to that controller or not..   mohammad

Comment: Did you check what shown in Network section in browser developer tools? Maybe there is an error in your PHP code.

Comment: so your ajax can't be sent, that's because your URL is wrong

Comment: then please tell me how to send it from javascript n access in controller

Answer (score 1):

replace your URL by this:

```
url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('product/dispatchdata'); ?>",
```

then try to send your json as follow: `data: {idList:JSON.stringify(idList)},`

Comment: thanks for ur ans bt still its nt working it give an error of [object object]

Comment: So instead of trying show error by `alert(error)` try `console.log(error)` and check what's in there.

Comment: @user3312547 this is another error, but now your ajax is sent successfully. check the way that you are using to collect the data from checkboxes.

Comment: is the method right which i have used  data: {idList:idList}, to pass data of javascript to controller ??

Comment: i got this when i alert idlist array .  [{"name":"autoId[]","value":"2840"},{"name":"autoId[]","value":"2829"},{"name":"autoId[]","value":"2836"},{"name":"autoId[]","value":"2835"}].  and i want to send all the autoid to controller through array @mohammad

Comment: If you are getting  [object object] in the alert then ajax request is fine,From controller  you should send json_encode data, and in javascript function on success you will get these data using "." operator.

Comment: Add your ajax response here. what you see in firebug console.

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/newtemplate/assets/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js" @AnamikaShrivastava

Comment: When ajax request hit then you can see this in the console, with detail what you are posting and what response you are getting. So i want to know the response of ajax url. And also add your controller function "dispatchdata".

Comment: +1 I hv some checkboxes on my page i need to collectthem in array and send them to controller for further procces.. 
and my controller function is  

public function actionDispatchdata()
    {    
       $idList = yii::app()->request->getPost("idList");
        
        foreach($idList as $d){
                
                $model=new Productpin;                $pinrec=$model->findByAttributes(array('epin_id'=>$d));                    
                    $pinrec->epin_disremark="s";
                    $pinrec->update(array(''epin_disremark'));
                    
            }      
    }

Comment: Add these three lines to your controller after for loop. 

`$result[]='success'; 
echo json_encode($result);
Yii::app()->end();`

If you are ajax request is working fine then alert will be success.

Comment: are you able to see ajax request in firebug console?

Comment: @AnamikaShrivastava no.

Comment: @Mohammad  can u explain this error while setting an html template to yii format  TypeError: $.param.querystring is not a function
 

options.url = $.param.querystring(options.url, settings.ajaxVar + '=' + id);

Comment: what is `querystring` function ?! please share the full code

Comment: @Mohammad i need steps or any link which shows how o convert html template to yii.. i have tried it before so it gives me this error as above.. i also dnt know wht is querytring functio,,,

Comment: what do you mean by converting html template to yii ? please make a new question for this issue and add a description and a code.

Comment: @Mohammad go to this link..   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453516/give-me-some-links-of-instrutcion-to-show-how-to-convert-html-page-to-yii-page

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo App::param('siteurl'); ?>products/ZipUpload",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        idList : $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").serializeArray()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mohammad said: "Replace your url with"

```
url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('product/dispatchdata'); ?>",
```

Further, if you fail in ajax call, the reason may be that the error is in your code in the controller. if you cant return successfully from controller, then you will get error in ajax... so try debugging step by step your controller action.