# How to make custom layout in Yii framework

Tags: php, html, layout, yii

I am new to yii please tell me how to convert html template to yii framework

give me some links for it to show some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your question clearly, anyway if you want to make a new Yii layout, you need to do these steps in general:

- create a new php file in the protected/views/layouts dir, name it
  new-temp.php for example. this page should print this var `<?php echo $content; ?>`
- create another php file in the same dir, name it new-temp-widget.php , this file should contain the following code : `<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/new-temp'); ?><div id="content"><?php echo $content; ?></div><?php $this->endContent(); ?>`
- Finally, to use this template for a certain action, just write this code inside the action function `$this->layout = '//layouts/new-temp-widget';`
  OR if you want to apply this template for the whole controller, add var inside the controller: `public $layout='//layouts/new-temp-widget';`

for more details see this link : [Working with Layouts in Yii](http://www.larryullman.com/2012/05/16/working-with-layouts-in-yii/)